# i have div's with check box i need when i click on it get the inner text of div i clicked on it only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div's with check box I need when I click on it get the inner text of div I clicked on it only

```js
      var serviceChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__toggle');
        var serviceTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.serveTitle');

        serviceChecked.forEach(function(listItem){
            listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                for (var t = 0; t < serviceTitle.length; t++) {
                    alert(serviceTitle[t].innerText);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<div class="checkdivwrp">                                        
   <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
   <div class="serveTitle">title 1</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">                                        
   <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
   <div class="serveTitle">title 2</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">                                        
   <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
   <div class="serveTitle">title 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `on('click'` and check if the checkbox is checked or not. If it is checked, get the inner text using `$(this).parent().find('.serveTitle').text()`:

```js
$(".checkbox__toggle").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    console.log($(this).parent().find('.serveTitle').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 1</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 2</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (now using indices to avoid parent and sibling confusion) :

```js
var serviceChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__toggle');
var serviceTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.serveTitle');
serviceChecked.forEach(function(service, index){
    service.addEventListener('click',function(){
        alert(serviceTitle[index].innerText);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="checkdivwrp">                                        
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 1</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">                                        
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 2</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">                                        
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: nextSibling can be anything. Ideally we should go by class name. like ```var child = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("serveTitle")[0];```

Comment: In his code it's not anything, it's serveTitle, always serveTitle!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Pure Javascript. You don't need any external libraries.

```js
var serviceChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__toggle');
var serviceTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.serveTitle');



serviceChecked.forEach(function(listItem) {
  listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
     var child = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("serveTitle")[0];
     
     alert(child.innerHTML)
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 1</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 2</div>
</div>
<div class="checkdivwrp">
  <input class='checkbox__toggle' type='checkbox'>
  <div class="serveTitle">title 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it working only if class of serveTitle  is parentElement in my real code this class contain in side div of div

Comment: this.parentElement basically refers to "checkdivwrp" in the context of element which is clicked on. As per your comments, it is not "serveTitle" element.  Explanation of above solution - just go to the parent of clicked element and search the element inside the body of parent. Thats an idle solution.

Answer (score 0):

edit: nextSibiling if it immediately follows the target element, if you don't know exactly where it is you can do the search below

you have to use e.target to get the one that is actually clicked, then do a check on the class names of children of its parent:

```
var serviceChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__toggle');

serviceChecked.forEach(function(listItem){
  listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var parent = e.target.parentNode; //you can use this instead of e.target
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (parent.childNodes[i].className == "serveTitle") {
        alert(parent.childNodes[i].innerText)
        break;
      }        
    }
  });
})
```